# web2py-@auth.requires() error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, web2py

I have add code in my db.py to add extra field before the `auth.define_tables(username=False, signature=True)`:

```
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user'] = (
    [Field('user_type',label="reg_type",default="Stu", requires=IS_IN_SET(['Stu, 'Com'],multiple=False))])
```

and I want to do some authentication in my action like the following:

```
@auth.requires(auth.user.user_type=="Stu",requires_login=True)
define someaction:
    code
```

However I get a error ticket when I run my application.

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_type'
```

And I have read the manual book

> > @auth.requires also takes an optional argument requires_login which defaults to True. If set to False, it does not require login before
> >     evaluating the condition as true/false. The condition can be a boolean
> >     value or a function evaluating to boolean.
>
> Note that access to all functions apart from the first one is
>   restricted based on permissions that the visitor may or may not have.
>
> If the visitor is not logged in, then the permission cannot be
>   checked; the visitor is redirected to the login page and then back to
>   the page that requires permissions.

So I can't understand what results in the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user is not logged in, `auth.user` is `None`. So, you must account for that in your condition:

```
@auth.requires(auth.user and auth.user.user_type == "Stu")
```

Note, `requires_login=True` is the default, so you don't have to specify that (and in this case, it would be unnecessary either way, as `auth.user` not being `None` implies the user is logged in).